# Kivy: Function\Method not working from another class

Tags: python, kivy

I made two buttons that have the same path to a function. Only one of the buttons works though. Both button should change the `lines` in the `circle`.

I've read on other post that I might need to 'link' the two classes together so that they can 'talk'. If anyone has any insight, please advise me!

Also, why does the `print` function work on both buttons but not the rest of the function?

Py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class Screen1(Screen):
    pass

class SM(ScreenManager):
    pass

class ButtonX(Button):
    def increaseX(self):
        TestApp().increase()

class TestApp(App):

    random_num_list = ListProperty([20, 40, 80])

    def increase(self):
        print(str(self.random_num_list))
        self.random_num_list = [90, 140, 220]

    def build(self):
        global sm
        sm = SM()
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Kv:

```
<Screen1>:
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}

            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1,1,1,1
                Line:
                    width: 5
                    circle: self.center_x, self.center_y, min(self.width, self.height) / 4, 0, app.random_num_list[0]

                Color:
                    rgba: .8,.1,.8,1
                Line:
                    width: 5
                    circle: self.center_x, self.center_y, min(self.width, self.height) / 4, app.random_num_list[0], app.random_num_list[1]

                Color:
                    rgba: .6,.6,1,1
                Line:
                    width: 5
                    circle: self.center_x, self.center_y, min(self.width, self.height) / 4, app.random_num_list[1], app.random_num_list[2]

                Color:
                    rgba: 1,.1,.4,1
                Line:
                    width: 5
                    circle: self.center_x, self.center_y, min(self.width, self.height) / 4, app.random_num_list[2], 360

        ButtonX:
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .55}
            size_hint: .2, .1
            text: 'Try first:\ndoesn\'t works'
            on_press: self.increaseX()

        ButtonX:
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .45}
            size_hint: .2, .1
            text: 'Try second:\nworks'
            on_press: app.increase()
<SM>:
    Screen1:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the problem I am going to modify the code:

```
# ...
class ButtonX(Button):
    def increaseX(self):
        t2 = TestApp()
        print("t2", t2)
        t2.increase()
# ...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = TestApp()
    print("t1", t1)
    t1.run()
```

Getting the following:

```
...
t1 <__main__.TestApp object at 0x7f8e750c38d0>
...
t2 <__main__.TestApp object at 0x7f8e71246320>
...
```

And clearly it is seen that they are 2 different objects, therefore when calling `increase()` it will not generate any modification to the current application.

In the case of .kv is used to [`app`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#value-expressions-on-property-expressions-ids-and-reserved-keywords) that is an object that indicates the application that is running, and in equivalent in .py is [`App.get_running_app()`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.get_running_app), so the solution is to use this last element.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class Screen1(Screen):
    pass

class SM(ScreenManager):
    pass

class ButtonX(Button):
    def increaseX(self):
        App.get_running_app().increase() # <---

class TestApp(App):
    random_num_list = ListProperty([20, 40, 80])

    def increase(self):
        print(str(self.random_num_list))
        self.random_num_list = [90, 140, 220]

    def build(self):
        sm = SM()
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Finally, do not use global variables because they are a headache when debugging.

Comment: Thank you for the information! You've been invaluable, seriously! Is it a problem if I have only have on global variable? In my app, I use `sm.current = 'screen_name'` to change the screens. Should I switch to `App.get_running_app().ScreenManager = 'screen_name` ?

Comment: @PetarLuketina use `App.get_running_app().root.current = 'screen_name'`, read https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.root

Comment: I was doing updates on my application and noticed that `App.get_running_app().some_function()` doesn't work anymore. Do you know the reason? It worked fine last week when you helped me.

Comment: @PetarLuketina You say: *I was doing updates on my application* then I can intuit that you have modified something that breaks the application, and I do not want to speculate because there could be n reasons.